# How to get role permissions ? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a bot that analyzes the server to find a flaw but I can't find how to know a precise authorization for a role? I have already tested this:

```
var role = message.mentions.roles.first()

if(role.permissions.has(Discord.Permissions.FLAGS.KICK_MEMBERS)){
     message.reply("YES") 
}
else message.reply("NO")
```

I always receive Yes as a message

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the if/else wrong, instead do it like this:

```js
var role = message.mentions.roles.first()

if (role.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.KICK_MEMBERS)) {
    message.reply({ content: "YES" })
} else {
    message.reply({ content: "NO" })
}
```

You don't need to put Discord infront of Permissions, and `message.reply('')` is deprecated, instead use `message.reply({ content: '' })`

```js
 Old: channel.send(embed);
 New: channel.send({ embeds: [embed, embed2] });

 Old: channel.send('Hello!', { embed });
 New: channel.send({ content: 'Hello!', embeds: [embed, embed2] });
```

Comment: But that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: try changing the message.mentions.roles.first() to message.mentions.members.first()

Comment: I'm looking for authorization from a role and not from a member